# Splitting a list of letters into subsequences starting with uppercase letters

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

Given a list of upper/lowercase characters, I'm trying to split it into subsequences that start with an uppercase and contain the next few (not necessarily positive number of) elements up until the next uppercase character.

For example, if I call a function that does this splitting action `camelsplit`, then I'd have

```
In[]:= camelsplit @ {"A", "b"}
Out[]= {{"A", "b"}}

In[]:= camelsplit @ {"A", "b", "C", "D", "e"}
Out[]= {{"A", "b"}, {"C"}, {"D", "e"}}
```

`SequenceCases` seems ideal for this, but I'm not sure how to dictate the pattern in cases where either 0 or more than 2 lowercase characters follow an uppercase character:

```
SequenceCases[
  {"A", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f"},
  {x_/;UpperCaseQ[x], y_/;!UpperCaseQ[y]} :> {x, y}
]

(* {{"A", "b"}, {"D", "e"}} *)
```

Attempting to replace `y_ /; !UpperCaseQ[y]` with something like `y__ /; AllTrue[!UpperCaseQ /@ {y}]` to handle the more-than-2 case doesn't seem to be right.

I've also tried using `Subsequences`, but I'm having similar trouble figuring out an appropriate `Select`-ion criterion to omit subsequences that ignore the condition of containing all the lowercase characters that follow the initial uppercase character:

```
Select[
  Subsequences[{"A", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f"}, {1, Infinity}],
  Count[#, x_ /; UpperCaseQ[x]] == 1 && UpperCaseQ @ First[#] &
]

(* {{"A"}, {"C"}, {"D"}, {"A", "b"}, {"D", "e"}, {"D", "e", "f"}} *)
```

Any suggestions not relying on `SequenceCases`/`Subsequences` and `Select` are welcome, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[{"A", "b", "C", "D", "e",  "f"}, {x_?UpperCaseQ, y___?LowerCaseQ} :> {x, y}]
```

> {{"A", "b"}, {"C"}, {"D", "e", "f"}}

Also

```
SequenceCases[{"A", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f"}, 
    {x_ /; UpperCaseQ[x], y___ /; AllTrue[LowerCaseQ]@{y}} :> {x,  y}]
```

> {{"A", "b"}, {"C"}, {"D", "e", "f"}}

You can also use [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
Split[{"A", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f"}, LowerCaseQ[#2] &]
```

> {{"A", "b"}, {"C"}, {"D", "e", "f"}}

Comment: Much appreciated! Seems I failed to notice an example of `PatternTest` usage in the docs for `SequenceCases`...

Comment: @user170231, my pleasure.